# How can I add an infinite scrolling in my MUI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Basically, I have this component and I have to add it an infinite scrolling. I've read MUI DataGrid but couldn't apply anything successfully.
I'm using GraphQL to fetch the data and i was using arrows to move to the next page but I have removed them.
I'm fetching 100 styles on each page.
Could anyone help me?

This is the component:

```
return (
    <>
      <StyledForm sx={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 72px)', p: 0, pt: 0, position: 'relative' }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={tableRows}
          columns={columns}
          loading={isStylesLoading || !tableRows}
          localeText={localeText}
          rowCount={totalCount}
          getRowClassName={(params: GridRowParams): string => {
                const isPinnedRow = params.row.id.includes('pinned');
                return `${classes.row} ${isPinnedRow ? classes.pinnedRow : ''}`;
          }}
          rowHeight={64}
          paginationMode="server"
          pageSize={size}
          classes={{
                root: classes.root,
                columnHeaders: classes.columnHeaders,
                columnHeaderTitle: classes.columnHeaderTitle,
                cell: classes.cell,
                columnSeparator: classes.columnSeparator,
                footerContainer: classes.footerContainer,
          }}
          components={{
                LoadingOverlay,
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unstable-nested-components
                Pagination: () => null,
          }}
          componentsProps={{
                row: {
                  onMouseEnter: handleRowMouseEnter,
                  onMouseLeave: handleRowMouseLeave,
                },
          }}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          disableColumnMenu
          onCellClick={handleCellClick}
        />
      </StyledForm>
      <StyleDialogDrawer isEdit={isEdit} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to infinitely expand the table when scrolling in x direction, DataGrid ist probably not the right component to use. I'd utilize a simple Table.
For infinite scrolling you follow this scheme:

1. Load 25 entries at first.
2. detect if user scrolled to the bottom of the page and trigger fetching the next 25 entries
3. append this new entries to the tableRows object

To trigger the fetching at reaching the bottom you can do something like the following:

```
const [reachedBottom, setReachedBottom] = useState(false);
// attach scroll observer 
useEffect(() => {
 const handleScroll = () => {
   const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
   const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight;
   const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

   if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 10) {
     setReachedBottom(true);
   }
 };

 window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

 return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
 };
}, []);
//
useEffect(() => {
 if(reachedBottom){
  /* trigger fetching here, extend the data object and reset the state*/
  setReachedBottom(false)
 }
}, [reachedBottom]);
```

Make sure the table is larger than the current viewport of the client.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the issue is that my boss wants to keep the DataGrid and I need to find the way to add infinite scrolling to that component. any other idea?

Comment: So it is intended to expand the view of the grid by adding more visible rows?  In that case extend the data object and the displayed rows by the same amount of entries by changing the pagination value. https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/

Comment: We want to remove the pagination and instead display all the data that we fetch using the graphql query. But I cannot find the solution for displaying an endless scrolling and displaying all the data in the datagrid

Comment: in the pagination option you set the pagesize accordingly to your desired multiple of rows you want to display. and after fetching more results you increase this number. pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 5 } },

Comment: nut we want to remove the pages and only fetch more data and show more rows, with the infinite scrolling, I was trying to implement fetchMore from the useLazyquery so that when i reach the bottom of the dataGrid I fetchMore data and show more rows when scrolling down but I don't get it work.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-updates/#infinite-loading